# Updating a sub-class of single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a single table inheritance where the parent is `Template` and the children are `LoginOne`, `LoginTwo`, `LoginThree`

Though, these three share sub-classes can all be updated through the same form and action. When declaring strong params I'm using `params.require(:template)` in the hope that this would cover all of the sub-classes, however it returns a `param is missing or the value is empty: template` error and it only works when I alter the strong params to be `params.require(:login_one)`

Is there any way I can get this to work without cluttering my actions with case statements?

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoginOne
    def self.model_name
      Template.model_name
    end
end
```

or

```
@submodel_instance.singleton_class.class_eval do
    def self.model_name
      Template.model_name
    end
end
```